# Texture change (and other state-change) costs on modern GPUs

Tags: 3d, xna, directx, gpu, direct3d

I'm writing a scene-graph based graphics engine for modeling purposes. I'm using XNA 4. 
On many places I have been reading, that texture changes (and other state changes) should be minimized during rendering (so I have to order my primitives by materials, etc.).

I created a small test application in XNA 4, which was rendering hundreds of stanford bunny models with a single texture, then doing the same toggling 2 different textures. There was no difference in rendering time (however I used small ~100x100 textures).

So my questions are:

- Should I really care about sorting my primitives by texture/color/other material parameters? Or is it less important on modern GPUs?
- What is the expectable percentage of performance loss, if I don't?
- Are there any other state changes, which can effect the performance?
- Where can I find some up to date literature/best practice guide about this?

Thank you for any help or links!

Comment: Might try asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get any responses here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

State changes haven't really been expensive for a *long* time. **Batches are expensive.** (And a state change necessitates a new batch). A batch is basically a call to a `Draw*Primitives` function.

[This PDF from nVidia](http://origin-developer.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8230/BatchBatchBatch.pdf?q=docs/IO/8230/BatchBatchBatch.pdf) explains it in detail. It also gives ideas for reducing your batch count.

Batches are a CPU-based limit (not GPU). That PDF lists "< 130 tris/batch" as the point where submitting batches dominates performance and the GPU sits idle waiting for more batches ([details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/03/31/an-elf-in-a-box.aspx)). It also says you get about 400 batches per frame, at 60 FPS, per 1GHz of CPU power dedicated to submitting batches. (Although the PDF is a bit old, so those figures are a bit out of date.)

My [answer on the gamedev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8521/the-practical-cost-of-swapping-effects/8533#8533) to a similar question should provide some more details. [This one too](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game/9289#9289).